# XML cusomter membership provider type c#

Tags: web-config, custom-membershipprovider

Here is my class declaration:

```
public class XmlMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {....}
```

and my web.config snipit:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomXmlMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
        <add name ="CustomXmlMembershipProvider" type="XmlMembershipProvider" xmlFilePath="App_Data\Userstore.xml"/> .....
```

I am not sure what to do from this point. I have done a ton of google searching but cannot find out why I am getting the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'XmlMembershipProvider'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type string should also include the assembly name that contains the XmlMembershipProvider.

```
 <add name="..." type="XmlMembershipprovider, MyAssembly" .../>
```

Comment: would this be located in the AssemblyInfo.cs file?

I tried to do this but I got the following error:
`Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'XmlMembershipProvider' from assembly 'CustomMembershipProvider'.`

Answer (score 0):

Only adding the reference to the assembly (as below) still gave errors, although it is a step in the right direction:

```
<add name="..." type="XmlMembershipprovider, MyAssembly" .../>
```

I found that the fully qualified reference to the assembly should ALSO be added as follows:

```
<add name="..." type="MyAssembly.XmlMembershipprovider, MyAssembly" .../>
```

Now it works.